# Single Instance Activity does not receive Input events

Tags: android, single-instance

I have 2 single instance activities in my app one is Log in Activity(A) which is also startup screen and other is kind of application home Activity(B). If I am on B and press home key on phone and go to home screen on phone then after a while if I go to 
Applications --> and Press my application icon --> I come back to B. But sometimes B is non responsive. If I look at logs I see touch events are going to A but B is displayed. Is that a bug in Android. It looks like android thinks since app is launched A is displayed but actually B is displayed. Has anyone faced similar issue

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know when you click home screen the application (Activity) goes into a "Pause" state and minimizes. When you click again the application system will call "onResume" and resume the last state of the application which is state B in your case.(I assume screen A and B are two activities). But if you want to get back to home screen of your app you should click back button not the home screen.

But if you are using two views its very possible to have problems as you are describing ( they are really not the problems or bugs). You need to be careful when you are catching the touch or motion events.